# Can't display the media player with the setAnchorView in Android

Tags: java, android

Here is my code to set a media controller, but the controller doesn't display on the screen.

```
void setMusicController() {
    musicController = new MusicController(this);
    musicController.setMediaPlayer(this);
    musicController.setAnchorView(findViewById(R.id.music_list));
    musicController.setEnabled(true);
}
```

Here is my subclass of `MediaController`:

```
public class MusicController extends MediaController {
    public MusicController(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
    }
}
```